# Grabbed numbers from an online page, converted to int(), but cannot multiply

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, type-conversion

I wrote a Python script that goes online, fetches a page, parses the page, locates a string of numbers (e.g, 5678), and stores it in num. Now, I need to perform some mathematical functions over this num. Why can't I do that?

Grabbed a line from page: The number is '6678'. Hence, line = "The number is '6678'"

```
c = ""
num = ''.join(c for c in line if c.isdigit())
int(num)
print num
try=(num*2)
print try
```

Error:

```
File "script", line 20
try=(num*2)
   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**Edit:** Changed the 'try' to 't'. Silly mistake! But, now I have a new error trying to do maths with 'num', further code:

```
new = (((num*3)+3)-1000)
print new
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>        File "602", line 22, in 
>        new = (((num*3)+2)-250)
>        TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found

Comment: Because `try` is part of the Python syntax (a statement)... use a different name

Comment: try is a reserved word for exception handling, you can't use it. Call your variable something else.

Comment: `int` will return an integer, not change `num`.

Comment: Also, if your line is "this is number 1 and this is number 2" - you'll end up with `num` == `'12'`...

Comment: Yes, the update won't work... because like @PeterWood says... you need to do something like `num = int(num)` - just using `int(num)` doesn't change `num` inplace... it returns an integer value of num, whose result you're just ignoring... so `num` is still a string...

Comment: Thank you! Such a silly mistake. However, I still can't use num for mathematical operations. Could you please take a look at the new error?

Comment: See below @intellikid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually reassign the casted number:

```
num = int(num) # num is a string right now
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurres because you're trying to use a variable named "try", which is a python's keyword. 
In addition,  you didn't saved the integer value of the number.
Finally,  your code should looks like this:

```
line = "4567"
num = ''.join(c for c in line if c.isdigit())
int_num = int(num)
print int_num
try1=(int_num*2)
print try1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a mock example.  If you are using beautiful soup to return the html content of a page you would need you split the read content. You want to create a list of words not characters so you don't run into the whole 1 vs 12 issue @Jon Clements brought up.

```
my_list = []
for word in data.split(" "):
    if word.isdigit():
        my_list.append(word)
    my_list = [int(i) for i in my_list]
print sum(my_list) * 2
```

Also, this is how try works:

```
try:
    pass #try to do some action
except:
    pass #if that action fails report
```